# Executing only one request out of 20 request from a thread - need to execute all request based on conditional statements

Tags: jmeter

I have 5 threads and each having multiple request (nearly 50).
When I start to execute all threads every thread running fine with all requests but only one thread (Thread3) not executing all required requests.

All my requests are executing through some conditional statement (ex: `If TC1=TRUE --> execute`).
In Thread 3 all conditions are correctly defined but always running only one request and others are not running, even not throwing any exception/error.

In jmeter log file there is also no exceptions/errors.
All requests (XML) also look to be executed fine.

Is there any way to find why threads are not running in jmeter?

Comment: all threads are finished including 3rd thread.but only one xml requested executed from 3rd thread and others are not.there are no exceptions/errors.                my achievement:i want to run each xml request from each thread based on conditional statements.            TH1-->rq1,rq2,rq3....all will execute based on condition                TH2-->rq1,rq2,rq3.....same as above.........                                      TH3-->rq1,rq2,rq3...                                                     ....................................................................TH50

Comment: Have you tried to debug the variable in that conditional statement? I have done a similar example with a counter, use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832348/jmeter-showing-the-values-of-variables)

Comment: Hey thanks for suggestion,am using debug sampler and view results there i can see all variables with values.here my problem is not at all entering into the requests(in thread3),i checked my condition also it looks good.